# Garry's mod Expression 2 for loop

Tags: for-loop, command-line-interface, garrys-mod

In a game called Garry's mod there an add on called wiremod. Inside wiremod there is expression 2 which is a conmand line basiced coding so  execute commands. The command For loop I'm having issues with because I can't do variable inside a variable. In CMD I could setlocal EnableLocalExtension and do !Var%Var%!
The code simpler is: (cap sensitive)

```
@inputs [GoCard1,GoCart2,GoCart3,GoCart4]:entity
X = 64
Y = 24

-N is the variable
-10 is max number
-1 is how much it increments by
for(N,10,1)
{
Menu:egpText(1,toString(GoCart1),vec2(X,Y)
Y+=24 -increase by 24
I++   -increase by 1
}
```

My problem is I can't change GoCart1 to GoCart2, GoCart3... Ect
Tried GoCartN but gives me an error GoCartN does not exists
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer I'm going to separate the code

```
@inputs [GoCard1,GoCart2,GoCart3,GoCart4]:entity
X = 64
Y = 24
T = table(GoCart1,GoCart2,GoCart3,GoCart4)
for(N,10,1)
{
Menu:egpText(1,"1. "+toString(T[N,entity]),vec2(X,Y)
Y+=24 -increase by 24
I++   -increase by 1
}
```

If anyone know how to put GoCart in the loop please let me know